# Disabled asp.net Text box return old value after enabling and changing text

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

my Problem is that I have an asp text box which has a value (text) but disabled(Enabled = "false")

after clicking on (Edit) button it becomes enabled (Enabled = "true") so I can change the text

--> After changing the text and click (Save) button , **it Takes the old value(text) before 
editing and save it instead of the new one**..

This Problem happens also with the **ReadOnly** property.

I'm stuck at this .. so any help I will be thankful.

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="AjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanelTelerik">
<tr>
  <td align="right" valign="top">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="InputForm" /> 
  </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="2" valign="bottom">
      <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="تـعــديـل" OnClick="Enable_Info" Font-Size="Large" />
      <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="إلـغـاء" OnClick="Cancel_Info" Font-Size="Large" Visible="false"/> 
  </td>        
</tr>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Here is The **C#** Code (*It's not necessary to write the SQL connection*) :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Email.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    Email.DataBind();

    Email.Enabled = false;

}

    protected void Enable_Info(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UpdateButton.Text == "تـعــديـل")
    {


        Email.Enabled = true;

        UpdateButton.Text = "حــفـظ";

        CancelButton.Visible = true;

    }
    else if (UpdateButton.Text == "حــفـظ")
    {

        AjaxPanel1.EnableAJAX = false;

        int CustomerId = System.Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["User"]["CustomerId"]);
        string email = Email.Text;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ArabShoppingConfiguration.DbConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Customer set Email = '" + email + "' where Id = '" + CustomerId + "'";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}

protected void Cancel_Info(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Email.Enabled = false;

    UpdateButton.Text = "تـعــديـل";

    CancelButton.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant markup and code behind, please?

Comment: BTW, don't ever use `throw ex;`. It screws up the stack trace. You should just use a `using` block for the `SqlConnection`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ... First time to know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so the issue is that you are setting Email.Text in your page load which runs every time the page loads to include all post backs. The page load fires before the Enable_Info method so it's changing the text back each time. All you need to do is modify your page_load code so that it only runs the FIRST time the page loads and NOT on postbacks:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    Email.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    Email.DataBind();

    Email.Enabled = false;
  }
}
```